# How to create an adaptive Android app

Tags: java, android, user-interface, dynamic, android-fragments

I want an Android app to be able to look and behave differently depending on what user group a user is in. For example, a user logs in, and the app tells a server which user it is. The information returned from the server can be different from user to user, so I want the app to be able to create different UI elements matching the information.

The kind of things that might change are:

- Sorting lists of data based on different indexes
- Dialogues with
  different input-fields, and a varying number of them
- Colours and icons might change, although that shouldn't be that hard.
- Maybe functions altogether might be in-/excluded, like adding/removing a field in a database, showing different graphs etc.

I'm sorry this is vague, maybe it's not clever to ask a question this general, but I don't know the specifics of the app yet, just the outline, and I'd like somewhere to start.

Is the only way to do this a bunch of

```
if(condition)
   //intitialize one GUI element
else if(condition2)
   //initialize another GUI element
```

until infinity, or is there another way?

Comment: It sounds like an `if/else` or `switch case` but its really hard to say without knowing more about what data you will be dealing with. This is a pretty broad question

Comment: On Android, there are a dozen ways to do what you're describing with different syntactic sugar and different programming patterns. Like codeMagic says, you will really have to be more specific in describing your use cases. We won't be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: I tried to add a few examples, I'm sorry it's vague, I don't know the details yet.

Answer (score 1):

Colleagues, why not to use the Strategy Pattern?

In our case I suggest to:

1) separate needed behavior in interfaces that will be implemented by concrete classes. E.g.:

```
public interface IViewBehavior {
    public void setSorting();
    public void setFields();
    public void setColors();

}
public interface IDataBehavior {
    public void setData(); 
}
```

2) use composition and integrate (add)  those behaviors into the Application object by delegating:

```
public class RickardApp extends Application {

    IDataBehavior dataBehavior;
    IViewBehavior viewBehavior;

    public void setDataBehavior(IDataBehavior dataBehavior) {
        this.dataBehavior = dataBehavior;
    }

    public void setViewBehavior(IViewBehavior viewBehavior) {
        this.viewBehavior = viewBehavior;
    }

}
```

set*Behavior() methods will define behavior of the app dynamically.
We need only to create “behavior”-classes when details will be known.